# Buildfire: How to remove the "saved" part?

Tags: buildfire

I could use some hints to get rid of the SAVED content in the [coupon Plugin](https://github.com/BuildFire/couponPlugin) -

- [Screenshot of the area i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2UYk.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

O.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to do this with code?

Comment: Hello attila226, 

Yes, i want to hide/remove the SAVED area in this plugin, but im not sure what lines to remove ...

:)

Answer (score 1):

In the file **widget/templates/List-Layout-1.html** file you will see the following code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 pull-left text-center primaryBackgroundTheme">
  <a class="whiteTheme stretch" ng- 
    click="WidgetHome.showSavedItems()">Saved</a>
</div>
```

You can just update it to the following:

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 pull-left text-center primaryBackgroundTheme"> 
</div>
```

The widget has 4 layouts, so depending on the layout that you want to use, you need to make sure to update the appropriate template.

Comment: Awesome, it seems to hide it, but now it leave a white field, any suggestions how to hide that, so it fits´ ?

Please check some examples -> https://imgur.com/a/VxsSl3c

Thank you attila!

O.

Comment: @OscarPedersen For that you'd need to change the column sizes. For example you may see "col-xs-3" for all 4 columns in your example. You need to increase the number of the other columns that you want to "col-xs-4", while changing the column that you want to hide to "hidden-xs".

Comment: It works with perfection!  - Thank you very much @attila226

Comment: @OscarPedersen Glad to hear it! If you're happy with the solution an upvote is appreciated.